# Write expression inside xml comment

Tags: xquery

I'd like to put xml comment in the output and put some expression inside the comment. How can I do that in xquery? If I have

```
<!-- {$var} -->
```

it is inserted literally, but I'd like to have a comment tag on the output with the *value* of `$var`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XQuery has a comment constructor, for example:

```
<test>
{
  let $x := 'hello world!'
  return comment {$x}
}
</test>
```

yields:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test><!--hello world!--></test>
```

Answer (score -2):

Would something like this work?

```
for $x in /* return <x><![CDATA[<!--]]>{$x}<![CDATA[-->]]> </x>
```

input

```
<test>hello comment</test>
```

output

```
<!--hello comment-->
```

Comment: Unfortunately it escapes the less-than char, see https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDbxm5

Comment: thats a bummer, the query site I used did not catch that. you can always just do a replace on the output?